Heap usage during SFTP operation of a very large file using Spring Integration
The requirement is to move large number of files from clients' infrastructure to my firm's infrastructure using SFTP.
The size of each file can be up to 5GBs. I am planning to use Spring Integration for this pipeline and use Spring batch jobs to process the files.
The example is available in the documentation at: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/spring-batch-integration/launching-jobs-through-messages.html
We will be allocated 16 VMs each having 4GB of heap. My doubt is that will a heap of 4 GB  be able to SFTP a file of 5 GB. Please advise.

If you stream a file, either writing it to disk, or processing as you read, you will just need a few kilobytes, no matter how big the file (assuming the processing itself doesn't accumulate all data in memory).

The question is on the SFTP phase of the requirement. Once the file is in my firm's infrastructure, I can use Spring Batch to process a file of any size.

That depends on how you do the SFTP, but if you write it to file, you will only have a few kilobytes for buffers. If you read it into memory, then yes, you're going to have a problem.

The buffer size option in SFTP is -b buffer_size
It specifies the buffer size used for data transfer. The default is 32768 bytes. The minimum allowed value is 1024. The maximum allowed value is 4194304 bytes.
e.g., provided in Spring Integration SFTP documentation at the following link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/sftp/session-factory.html
I would need to profile the application for available heap and set this buffer size accordingly so that application does run out of heap and throw a OOME.
